# XML parsing class cast exception

Tags: android, xml-parsing, classcastexception

```
<xml>
<Table_Info>
<SeenStatus>0</SeenStatus>
<NewLimit>0</NewLimit>
</Table_Info>
</xml>
```

this is data i am getting from server end and the code to parse it is as follow-

```
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory
                    .newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = db.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Table_Info");

            /** Assign textview array length by arraylist size */

            System.out.println(".....prinyt user data..." + url);

            for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {

                Node node = nodeList.item(i);

                Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;

                NodeList costList1 = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("SeenStatus");
                Element costElement1 = (Element) costList1.item(0);
                costList1 = costElement1.getChildNodes();
                seen_stat_server = ((Node) costList1.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                String mchaal = min_chaal;
                System.out.println("...prinyt user data....." + min_chaal);
                NodeList costList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("NewLimit");
                Element costElement = (Element) costList1.item(0);
                costList = costElement.getChildNodes();

                min_chaal = ((Node) costList1.item(0)).getNodeValue();
                System.out.println("...prinyt user data....." + total);
                String str2 = total;
```

now i am getting exception-

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.harmony.xml.dom.TextImpl cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Element

on this line->

```
`NodeList costList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("NewLimit");
                    Element costElement = (Element) costList1.item(0);`
```

actually i am new to xml parsing so please tell me whats the problem

Comment: Change `Element costElement = (Element) costList1.item(0);`  to `Element costElement = (Element) costList.item(0);` and at which line getting issue

Comment: `Element costElement = (Element) costList1.item(0);` on this line there is error

Comment: and there are two child tags so both elements `costElement` and `costElement1` are necessary

Comment: i think this problem is due to some data type problem at server side...

Comment: yup the problem solved, the problem was arising due to the some data type problem on server side...made some changes on server side and done

Answer (score 0):

I'll recommend you go for XMLPullParser coz its way faster than SAX and DOM parsers.

below is the XMLPullParserHandler class -

```
public class XmlPullParserHandler {

String text;
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

public String parse(InputStream is) {

    try {

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();

        parser.setInput(is, null);

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            String tagname = parser.getName();
            switch (eventType) {

                case XmlPullParser.TEXT:
                    text = parser.getText();
                    break;

                case XmlPullParser.END_TAG:
                    if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("SeenStatus")) {
                        builder.append("SeenStatus = " + text);
                    } else if (tagname.equalsIgnoreCase("NewLimit")) {
                        builder.append("\nNewLimit = " + text);
                    }
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
            eventType = parser.next();
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return builder.toString();
}


}
```

below is the XMLPullParser class

```
public class XMLPullParser extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView txtXML;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_xmlpull_parser);


    txtXML = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtXML);

    try {

        XmlPullParserHandler parser = new XmlPullParserHandler();
        InputStream is = getAssets().open("sampleXML.xml");

        String xmlOutput = parser.parse(is);
        txtXML.setText(xmlOutput);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}

}
```

I have fetched the xml from assets but u can simply pass the returned response Inputstream to parse it successfully.

Comment: ok thanks i will try it, but actually my problem is cast exception.. will it vanish with XMLPullParser ?

Comment: @sud: I have parsed the xml that u have mentioned in Q and it parsed it succesfully.